# How to get this type of page transition animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to get this type of page transition effect in flutter. I tried all the packages found on pub.dev but I didn't  get this one.

Comment: Hey. While I do think, the question is perfectly valid, your request "Will anyone please write a simple two page navigation code with this animation" is not. SO is not a code writing service :) I imagine you get better responses with a different attitude

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @MarianTheisen. It was on the sense that will someone "help me on this".  I edited the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route scaleIn(Widget page) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, page) {
      var begin = 0.0;
      var end = 1.0;
      var curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
      return ScaleTransition(
        scale: animation.drive(tween),
        child: page,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

And use it like so:

```
Navigator.push(context, scaleIn(NewPage()));
```

Comment: Josteve,i want to use this animation on every page of my app. How can i use this in PageTransitionsBuilder and link to themedata?

Comment: Hey @NarayanPoudel, How do you mean `link to theme data`?